# How to order get_categories() in the same order as the menu?

Tags: categories

I'm using a theme and I noticed that it dynamically displays an array of the categories in the menu:

[image]

I need the same list of categories but within different HTML tags for my footer. Currently this is what I have in my footer:

[image]

footer.php:

```
<?php
      $categories = get_categories();
      foreach($categories as $category) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
      }
?>
```

As you can see, it's not in the same order as the one in the menu.

I tried to use that as a hint to how I would loop through the categories. However, when I try to find the template for the header, I notice that it just points to this and I don't see any of the PHP / HTML:

```
    <nav class="main-navigation">

      <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
          'fallback_cb' => 'false',
        ) );
      ?>

    </nav><!-- /.main-navigation -->
```

I tried looking everywhere for a `header-menu.php` file but it doesn't seem to exist, possibly because it's coming from the theme..?

```
register_nav_menus( array(
  'header-menu' => esc_html__( 'Header', 'neori' ),
) );
```

Here's a pic of what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no header-menu.php, that bit of code is creating a WP Menu, have a look [at this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).

You could create another menu for the footer.  Or if you need more control of the markup, you could use your category code, which uses get_categories() and then sort them how you like.  More info on [get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/).

Here is an example of sorting by name.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
) );
```

So your the entire code block would look like this.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
) );

foreach($categories as $category) {
  echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
}
```

**Edit (Copy Main Navigation in Footer):** You can copy your main navigation to the footer by adding this code in your footer.php.

```
<nav class="footer-navigation">
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'fallback_cb' => 'false',
        ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

**Edit 2 (Array of Nav Items):**

You can build your own array using wp_get_nav_menu_items(). [Docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)
 and [Examples here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111060/retrieving-a-list-of-menu-items-in-an-array)

Comment: Hi Riddle. Would there be a way to sort the categories in the same order as the menu though? From the looks of the header menu (the 1st pic I pasted), it doesn't look like it's in alphabetical order. Is there another field I'm not aware of like `sortOrder` or something?

Comment: Oh! I just realized I need to grab the menu items, not the categories. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying todo?  Can you just duplicate the same menu in the footer?

Comment: I just want an array of the menu items in the same order, loop through each, and output something like `<a href="$menu_item->url">$menu_item.title</a>`

Comment: Updated to include a pic (except it wouldn't be Culture, Web, etc, it would be Editorial, World, etc like the header menu)

Comment: Right.  So why not just use the same menu for the footer?  You can target it specifically with css to make it look however you want

Comment: Sorry this is the first time I've done this. How would I use the same menu and customize the CSS? Would you be able to show me how to 1) grab an array of the menu items 2) loop through them and make an anchor tag for each?

Comment: "How would I use the same menu and customize the CSS?"  see my last edit

Comment: if that isnt what you want, then you will want to use wp_get_nav_menu_items to build your custom array - added info on that to answer